# Ruby on Rails - select everything from two tables in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

In my companies_controller, I have the following:

```
def show
@company = Company.find(params[:id], 
:conditions => ['companies.id = addresses.company_id'], 
:joins => [:address])
respond_with(@company) do |format|
format.xml { render :xml => @company}
end
end
```

Which results in:

```
SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "addresses" ON "addresses"."company_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "companies"."id" = ? AND (companies.id = addresses.company_id) LIMIT 1
```

in the server console.

HOWEVER, I'm trying to get SELECT *, so I get all the columns from BOTH tables. The reason I'm trying to do this is because I need a curl on companies/1.xml to return all the data. Maybe I need to create a new controller for both the company and address models?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Doesn't your `Company` model already specify a `has_one` or `has_many` with addresses? If the `Address` has a corresponding `belongs_to` it'll be eager-loaded by default. You're doing work the framework already does for you.

Comment: Check out the [Rails Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more info.

Comment: Dave, yes - the Company model has_one :address and the address model belongs_to :company. I'm able to display address fields on the on the companies/show.html.erb page. The problem comes when I run curl http://localhost:3000/companies/1.xml from the Terminal. It only returns nodes from the companies table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `:include` like this:

```
render :xml => @company.to_xml :include => [:address]
```

Comment: Dave, I'm running rails 3.1.1, so I used format.xml { render :xml => @company, :include => [:address]} and it works! Thanks for the link to the Associations Guide. I have much reading to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: @h8windows Cool, yeah, wasn't sure which version to target. Remember to accept answers so future visitors get a visual indication regarding what helped. I recommend spinning through all the Rails guides; they're superficial, but great starting points.